# Brightness keys do not modify actual brightness

Tags: brightness

I am really new to linux, sorry if this is an easy question.

I recently installed Ubuntu on an old macbook with next to no issues, except for the fact that the backlight does not respond to the brightness buttons, but they do cause a response in the gui. By using xrandr in the terminal I can change the brightness manually, which makes me think that the buttons are somehow changing the wrong value.

Basically, I can change the brightness with terminal and not with the brightness keys, and any help on fixing this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please tell us which driver are you using, and which ubuntu version. Can you also paste the contents of /etc/X11/xorg.conf